# Passing Properties to Spring Boot Datasource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Im trying to pass some properties ( kerboros and SSL related ) to the datasource, that are needed to make the connection.

```
-Djkd.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2  
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/2/jaas.conf  
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/2/krb5.conf
```

As can be seen, these are actually VM level system properties needed for making the connection to the database.

1. ( Assuming - I don't know yet. But this is a general question for the sake of understanding - they would work if I pass them as properties to the datasource ) How will I set arbitrary properties to the database while making a connection ( Just like the JDBC interface allows you : *DriverManager.Connection getConnection(String url, Properties info)* )
2. Also, is there a way to pass VM arguments to spring boot through application.yml ? ( Maybe it forks in order to achieve this ? )

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot has a way of loading externalized configuration. It goes through the sources of where it would load configuration in this order:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Among this list, you will find `application.properties` or `application.yml` (doesn't matter which you use, just a different format). They are pretty low on the list so the properties in them will be overridden by properties with the same name passed through commandline or sth else.

But the point is, Spring doesn't care where exactly does the property comes from `application.yml`, command line, system environment it will load them all, but things higher in that list will override properties lower in the list if defined more than once.

Spring data source is defined  in the following format in `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasrouce:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: your_db_username
    password: your_db_password
```

remember that indentation is important in .yml files. Provided you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, Spring Boot will automatically configure datasource based on these properties alone.

Regarding passing arguments to JVM, Spring Boot only processes arguments necessary for its beans (e.g. datasouce) so I don't think there is a straightforward way of making that work via its properties.

Comment: Thanks @asagarov. I was asking if I put spring.datasource.xxx=yyy, behind the scene if this would result in a property xxx=yyy being passed to the jdbc DriverManager.Connection getConnection(String url, Properties info) ) ?

Comment: yes most likely that line of code is somewhere there called by Spring. That is not important since Spring will instantiate ready to use DataSource bean that you can use with JdbcTemplate or Hibernate or JpaRepository.